# Visual Studio - Remove error 'gutter' navigation next to scrollbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm just trying to maximize my editing space really never use this thing at all.  Anybody know the option to remove it?[image]

Comment: would you happen to know which one? My extension manager only lists nuget, ViEmu, and VS Color theme editor.  Maybe it's r#?

Comment: I assume it's Resharper.  Check its options.

Comment: It's Resharper, but I don't think it provides an option to remove it... checking now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Resharper's "Marker Bar".  Currently, there is no way to [hide or remove it](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/286118) (other than removing Resharper).